# Extracting string from Braces

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a string like this "`(myname)babu(paritala)`".

I have a problem in extracting "`babu`" from it. I want to extract "`babu`" from that.

How can I extract "`babu`" from it using C#?
I have tried using `string.extract`, but it's not working.

Comment: can you show your code from what you've tried? How did you use string.extract?

Comment: you'll probably have to add a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

You can use regular expressions. If your strings will always have that pattern this will work:

```
string myString = "(myname)babu(paritala)";
Match myMatch = Regex.Matches(myString, @"(\w+)\w+(\w+)")[1];
string matchedPattern = myMatch.Value;
```

Comment: Well you would have to escape the parens to match them... it wouldn't even work for that input.

Comment: I have ran the code above and it works as intended. The value of matchedPattern is babu. Please let me know if you get a different output.

Comment: Let me reiterate I have ran this code and the retrieved value for matchedPattern is babu. I appreciate the critique but I have ran this multiple times with the sample input. So if you ran it and got something different, let me know. If not, you could easily test your assumption and run the snippet.

Comment: Yes, your code will produce `babu` for this specific case but it does it in a roundabout way. Your regular expression is defining 2 groups of word characters separated by more word characters. Collectively, it's just word characters.  Using this logic, it could have just been `\w+`. But that's not what you're intending... you're probably trying to match the parentheses. To match them, you must escape the parentheses because they are used for grouping and has special meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on that! I'll make sure I do some more reading on regular expressions